# Return duplicate items from Custom List<T> not in order C#

Tags: c#, linq, duplicates

I have a collection of (6) number sequences in a custom List

**Example of List**

**1.** 1,2,3,4,5,6

**2.** 2,1,8,9,8,4

**3.** 6,5,4,3,2,1

Basically, I need to get the same groups of numbers which aren't necessarily in the same order. So for the example above, I would need to return either `1,2,3,4,5,6` or `6,5,4,3,2,1`

I have the following which works for single numbers, but not 6 number groups.

```
var dupes = numCol.GroupBy(x => x)
    .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
    .Select(x => x.Key)
    .ToList();
```

Whats the best and most efficient way to do this?

Thanks.

**Edit:**

Sample of my custom list structure is below..

```
 public class Numbers
 {
     private int _First;
     public int First
     {
         get { return _First; }
         set { _First = value; }
     }
     private int _Second;
     public int Second
     {
         get { return _Second; }
         set { _Second = value; }
     }
     ...
```

Comment: That custom list of yours doesn't implement `IEnumerable` and its generic cousin, which would make iterating over that more difficulty that necessary

Comment: You need to somehow make the individual "lists" equivalent. A simple way to do this would be to internally keep a sorted list of elements, and then compare using that. And do you really need that "Numbers" class to be mutable? Are you modifying it after constructing it?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen +1 thats exactly what I did, sorting the items made it easier to compare. I don't really need Numbers class, but thought it would be a cleaner way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

If the order is not important use **Set** instead of **List**.

List is an ordered sequence of elements whereas Set is a distinct list of elements which is unordered.

If you realy need a List, you will need to iterate the list to do that. There is not more efficient to do it. Linq functions do that under the hood, they are just shorcuts for developers.